# Iptables: проброс портов

Tags: iptables, ubuntu, сервер

Пытаюсь пробросить порт на Ubuntu. Постановка задачи: есть шлюз с внешним адресом EXTERNAL_IP и внутренним 192.168.0.1. В локальной сети есть сервер 192.168.0.2, на котором крутится Apache. Внешний интерфейс шлюза p2p1, внутренний p2p2. Надо, чтобы при заходе на EXTERNAL_IP браузером снаружи (работает) и изнутри сети (НЕ РАБОТАЕТ) отдавался сайт, который крутится на внутреннем сервере. Написал следующие правила. Где я неправ?

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING —dst EXTERNAL_IP -p tcp —dport 80 -j DNAT —to-destination 192.168.0.2  
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING —dst 192.168.0.2 -p tcp —dport 80 -j SNAT —to-source 192.168.0.1  
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT —dst EXTERNAL_IP -p tcp —dport 80 -j DNAT —to-destination 192.168.0.2  
iptables -I FORWARD 1 -i p2p1 -o p2p2 -d 192.168.0.2 -p tcp -m tcp —dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: @graalogosh, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему полным забиванием на iptables и переходом на rinetd. Да, для хайлода не сойдет, грузит процессор обработкой пакетов, но у меня в пике 20 клиентов, так что не очень страшно

Answer (score 1):

Ваша ситуация выглядит примерно так?

Если машина 192.168.0.X - находится в той-же сети, что и сервер, то, при правильно настроенных маршрутах на машинах, запросы к веб-серверу должны идти напрямую и не затрагивать роутер.

[image: Диаграма сети]

Comment: Да, по внутреннему адресу 192.168.0.2 сайт прекрасно видно без всяких настроек дополнительных. Но для меня важно, чтобы этот сайт открывался изнутри по EXTERNAL_IP, чтобы у юзеров сайт открывался нормально вне зависимости от того, внутри они сети или снаружи

Comment: так. то-есть у вас есть софт (собственный? то-есть вы можете его менять? или только конфиги к нему) который должен получать доступ к веб-серверу. Пользователи этого софта - это узкий круг людей? По-сути  - локальные это пользователи? или вообще могут быть левые граждане?

Answer (score 1):

Можно решить задачу на уровне DNS, то есть чтобы для локальных пользователей хост резолвился в 192.168.0.2, а для запросов извне в EXTERNAL_IP.

Данное решение возможно, если вы можете контролировать локальный DNS.

Comment: Да. Я так и написал выше:)

Comment: Я имел в виду bind views

https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/BIND/Tutorial/ru

Ну а домен можно взять и бесплатно, например, 3-го уровня, см. http://www.dot.tk/ru/index.html

Comment: Мало того, можно создать на внутреннем DNS-сервере зону с именем сайта (`www.domain.com`), в ней создать А-запись с пустым именем и дать ей внутренний IP-адрес веб-сервера. В итоге пользователи, ходящие извне, эту запись не видят, получают обычную публичную запись, а внутренние посылают запрос к DNS-серверу, у него есть запись про этот узел и он не отдает внешний узел, а отдает внутренний. И волки сыты, и овцы целы.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d EXTERNAL_IP -p tcp -dport 80 -j DNAT -to-destination 192.168.0.2
# Если клиенты из внутренней сети пытаются зайти на сайт, используя внутренний адрес шлюза. Если используется внешний адрес - заменить 192.168.0.1 на EXTERNAL_IP.
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 192.168.0.1 -p tcp -dport 80 -j DNAT -to-destination 192.168.0.2    
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d 192.168.0.2 -p tcp -dport  80 -j SNAT -to-source 192.168.0.1
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Пользователи заходят по внешнему EXTERNAL_IP адресу как изнутри сети, так и снаружи. Я не смогу им объяснить, что надо использовать разные адреса. В чем тогда разница между первой и второй строкой? (комментарий не учитываю)
Залил правила как есть - все равно, снаружи работает, изнутри нет

Comment: Пардон. Никакой разницы нет, оставьте только одну строку.

Comment: А насчет объяснения пользователям про разные адреса - проблема решается добавлением двух A-записей в dns, для внутреннего и внешнего ip.

Comment: Проблема в том, что руководство зажимает деньги на доменное имя. Приходится в нужные места в пользовательском софте пихать айпишник. Мне все таки придется выбить деньги на домен, чтобы появилась возможность по разному разрешать его имя снаружи и внутри сети?

Comment: Ну необязательно же домен покупать. Внутренний dns с доменом firma.local вполне может решить Вашу проблему.

Comment: Допустим, изнутри это сработает. Но этот же софт не сможет достучаться по  firma.local снаружи.